# Content Type and Sub Pages?

Tags: nodes

I have a drupal 6 instance and I want to make it so when I create a content type (for example movies) it would create 2 sub pages (reviews, and photos). So if I went to

www.site.com/movie-BLAHBLAH/ it would load the node content type info
and

www.site.com/movie-BLAHBLAH/reviews/ it would display a page where I could theme the page.tpl.php file to do what i want it to do. and same with the other one.

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Drupal 6, there is the [CCK Fieldgroup Tabs](http://drupal.org/project/cck_fieldgroup_tabs) module.

> Display CCK fieldgroups in tabs. Enables splitting up content onto tabs in both editing and display.
> Requires Tabs module as well as Content and Fieldgroup modules, part of [CCK](https://www.drupal.org/project/cck). For Drupal 5.x, Tabs module is part of [Javascript Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/jstools). For Drupal 6.x, [Tabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/tabs) is a separate module.

That project is seeking new maintainers and no longer developed by its maintainers. It does not have any release for Drupal 7 or more recent Drupal releases, which means that, as the project page for that module suggests, a Drupal 7 or a Drupal 8 site should use the [Field Group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group) module, which is now compatible with Drupal 9 and Drupal 10.

> Fieldgroup will, as the name implies, group fields together. All fieldable entities will have the possibility to add groups to wrap their fields together. Fieldgroup comes with default HTML wrappers like vertical tabs, horizontal tabs, accordions, fieldsets or div wrappers.
>
> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this. Just like the node module has create an url where all nodes are visible: `node/[nid]` you could create path for `node/[nid]/review` and create a custom page that display the reviews for that node.

This is done by the use of `hook_menu`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like what you really ought to do is create 3 content types, movies, reviews & photos. And use something like [references](http://drupal.org/project/references) or [relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation) to keep them related to each other.